# Алгоритм прохождения линии через клетки

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте.

Есть сетка ячеек, у каждой из которых есть свои координаты. Нужно определить через какие ячейки проходит линия, соединяющая 2 заданных точки.

[image]

Этот алгоритм нужен, что бы нарисовать отрезок между этими двумя точками, заполняя ячейки по полученным координатам.

Что-то голова вообще не варит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

составте уравнение прямой на основе координат 2-х точек)
а дальше приращая аргумент Х от мин к мак по уравнению прямой вы получите соответствующую координату Y) и будете рисовать в цикле точку по полученным координатам

Comment: да незачто) только не забудте Y приводить к целому числу

Comment: вообще-то, для этого есть готовый [алгоритм Брезенхема](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0), а ваш вариант не сработает, если |dx| < |dy| (например, x1 == x2).

Comment: и в чем отличия ?)) представленный вами аолгоритм основан на уравнении прямой точки. то что возникает проблемы ввиду дискритизации монитора (точки не делятся) - так ето я ему написал что придется привести к ЦЕЛОМУ!- и вот тут заметте - я не написал округлить по мат законам - пусть человек сам додумается как ему и в каких случаях приводить к целому

Comment: ну, ваш алгоритм для каждого икса производит единственный игрек. а представьте себе теперь, что линия вертикальная. ну или почти вертикальная.

Comment: вертикальная линия имеет уравнение вида X=a, на этапе вычисления урвнения линии - все случаи нада и рассматривать. Да и смысл форума - не предлагать готовое решение, а подсказать алгоритм, отправную точку- а дальше сам , иначе никто ничему никогда не научится